# Exam package, award points by part, but droppoints by question

Tags: exam

(MWE at the bottom) I am using the exam package. I had the following basic layout for my questions

```
\question[10] question 1
    \begin{parts}
    \part part a
    \part part b
    \end{parts}
    \droppoints
```

which was working fine and dropping the points where I wanted them -- at the end of the question, bottom of the page

I decided to award points by parts, but I still want the point total after the whole question. But I'm being told \droppoints is an "undefined control sequence" when I try moving the point values to the parts

```
\question question1
\begin{parts}
\part[5] part a
\part[5] part b
\end{parts}
\droppoints
```

I cannot find what's wrong (and yes, I tried the documentation).

Note that I also have these settings (which I doubt would affect this)

```
\pointsdroppedatright
\bracketedpoints
\pointpoints{pt}{pts}
\marginpointname{ pts}
```

Here's an MWE

```
\documentclass[fleqn,addpoints,answers]{exam}
%\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools,commath}

% For the exam package
% POINT DISPLAY
\pointsdroppedatright   % Display points lower right
\bracketedpoints        % square bracket around points
\pointpoints{pt}{pts}
\marginpointname{ pts}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}

\question%[10]
Question 1
\begin{parts}
  \part[5]
    Calculate the future value annuity factor $s_{n|i}$.
    \part[5]
    Use your answer from (a) to find the future value.
\end{parts}
\droppoints

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

(MWE at Bottom)

The `\droppoints` commands takes the optional parameter of `\question` (or `\part`, see the question 3 below).

If you use parts and you want to get the sum of all parts, then you must use `\droptotalpoints`.

If you want to see also the points for each part, then you may use the `\droppoints` inside the parts-environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[fleqn,addpoints,answers]{exam}
%\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools,commath}

% For the exam package
% POINT DISPLAY
\pointsdroppedatright   % Display points lower right
\bracketedpoints        % square bracket around points
\pointpoints{pt}{pts}
\marginpointname{ pts}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}

\question
Question 1
\begin{parts}
  \part[5]
    Calculate the future value annuity factor $s_{n|i}$.
    \part[5]
    Use your answer from (a) to find the future value.
\end{parts}
\droptotalpoints


\question[12]
Question 1
\begin{parts}
  \part[5]
    Calculate the future value annuity factor $s_{n|i}$.
    \part[5]
    Use your answer from (a) to find the future value.
\end{parts}
\droppoints


\question
Question 1
\begin{parts}
  \part[7]
    Calculate the future value annuity factor $s_{n|i}$.
\droppoints
    \part[7]
    Use your answer from (a) to find the future value.
\droppoints
\end{parts}
\droptotalpoints


\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to use `\droptotalpoints`. See section 4.3.9 "Adding up the points for a question" of the documentation. I've used version 2.5.

It seems that `\droppoints` is only allowed "inside" a question, part, subpart, ... but not out of any context. I guess the `parts` environment breaks the scope of `\question` in terms of the availability of the command `\droppoints`.